# How to create a 3D symbol in QGIS to represent a cylindrical culvert?

Tags: qgis, 3d

Does anyone know if its possible to create a 3D symbol in QGIS to represent a cylindrical culvert? If I use a rectangular polygon base, all of the settings I've looked through so far create a box from a polygon shape. If I use a point symbol, the cylinder option is oriented vertically. There doesn't seem to be an option for a horizontal cylinder.

Comment: Which geometry type, line?

Comment: It doesn't matter to me as long as it results in a horizontal cylinder, since I am drawing the layer from scratch.